# issue with accessing data from my component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i am passing data to my component and all data assigned to my component correctly "i checked it at vue dev tool it's assigned correctly" but when i am try to access the id attribute from specific component it's return latest component id attribute not the current component attribute

*NOTE* all you need be care about in parent component code the line of calling child component

parent component code :

```
    <tr v-for="object in data">

        <td v-for="field in fields">{{object[field.includes(' ') ? field.replace(' ','_') : field]}}</td>

        <td v-if="Actions">

            <a v-for="action in Object.keys(Actions)"

               @click.prevent="determineAction(action,object[Key])"

               :href="getActionURI(object[Key],action)"

               :class="getBtnClass(action)">

                {{action}}

            </a>

        </td>

        <edit-modal v-show="displayEditModal" @EditModalClose="hideEditMoodal()"                             
         :data="object" :fields="editFields"></edit-modal>

    </tr>
```

here is the child component code :

```
<section class="modal-card-body">

  <form>

        <div class="form-group" v-for="(field,index) in fields">

            <label>

                    {{index}}

                    <input :type="field" class="form-control" :placeholder="'Please enter ' + index"     
                           :value="data[index]" @input="index = $event.target.value">

            </label>

        </div>                

  </form>

</section>

<footer class="modal-card-foot">

    <button class="btn btn-success btn-block" @click="update">Update</button>


</footer>



<script>

export default{
    props:{
        data: {
            type: Object,
            required : true
        },
        fields: {
            type: Object,
            required : false
        }
    },
    data(){
        let temp = {};
        for(let field in this.fields){

            temp[field] = this.data[field.includes(' ') ? field.replace(' ','_') : field];
        }
        return temp;
    },
    methods:{
        fireEvent(eventName,data = null){
            window.Events.fire(eventName,data);
        },
        update(){
            console.log(this.data.id);
        }
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: can you try changing the prop name to something else other than data?

Comment: same problem @JegadeshBS